# Can not use onmouseover event on select option in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

Updated code:

```
function getElements()
  {
  var x=document.getElementsByTagName("option");

var el = document.getElementById('selectDept');
el.onmouseover = function( myevent ) {
   // event = event || window.event.srcElement;
if(myevent && myevent.target){
    if ( myevent.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'option' ) {
        alert(myevent.target.innerHTML);
    }
}
else if(window.event)
{
   if ( window.event.srcElement.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'select' ) {
        alert('s');
    }
 
}
};
```

but still not working in IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you still set a mouseover event handler on the whole select, and target the event property if the target is an option element, do X action?

```
var el = document.getElementById('foo')
el.onmouseover = function( event ) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target ? event.target : event.srcElement;
    if ( target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'option' ) {
        alert('option');
    }
}
```

Updated code:

http://jsbin.com/olusi

Comment: updated with pseudo code example, I just typed it in the post I didn't actually test this out. You may need to account for bubbling with stopPropagation and such though, let me know how it goes.

Comment: I think you need the event.srcElement in IE to get which element triggered the event. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534638%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: i was looking that up because I forgot to account for the target, ty though.

Comment: I updated with a live example... let me know if it doesn't work in IE.

Comment: event = event || window.event;
what is this used for ?

Answer (score 7):

IE does not support events on the **option** element.  You can try as @meder says to add a handler on the parent select and then inspect the event to see which option was moused over.

PS these were known bugs in IE6 (and reported in IE7 and IE8 beta testing - and rejected for fixing to date) :-(

Maybe IE9 will support them?

Comment: IE9 will not support them apparently! at least not in beta as of 1-16 :(